# Need help fixing this C Socket ICMP Program

Tags: c, sockets, icmp

i have a C program that's able to receive ICMP requests and display them, but however will not send out any ICMP requests itself from what I've seen using Wireshark.

I have included the required libraries and i'm using a IP header file and ICMP header file that's omitted.

Any help would be appreciated. Please ignore the random Printf statements, there just to help me out.

Thanks

**

```
***IP.h*****

#ifndef __IP_H__
#define __IP_H__

struct iphdr {

   uint8_t   hdrlen:4;    
   uint8_t   version:4;
   uint8_t   ecn:2;       
   uint8_t   dscp:6;     
   uint16_t  length;
   uint16_t  ident;
   uint16_t  fragoff:13;
   uint16_t  flags:3;
   uint8_t   ttl;
   uint8_t   protocol;
   uint16_t  checksum;
   uint32_t  srcip;
   uint32_t  dstip;
   uint32_t  options[ ];  
} __attribute__((__packed__));

#endif // __IP_H__

****ICMP.H****

#ifndef __ICMP_H__
#define __ICMP_H__

struct icmphdr {
   uint8_t   type;         
   uint8_t   code;          
   uint16_t  checksum;      
   uint16_t  id;          
   uint16_t  seqNum;       
   uint32_t  data[ ];       
} __attribute__((__packed__));


char * messages[ ] = {
   "Echo reply",
   "Type 1",
   "Type 2",
   "Destination unreachable",
   "Source quench",
   "Redirect",
   "Type 6",
   "Type 7",
   "Echo request",
   "Router advertisement",
   "Router discovery",
   "Time exceeded",
   "Parameter problem",
   "Timestamp request",
   "Timestamp reply",
   "Information request (obsol.)",
   "Information reply (obsol.)",
   "Address mask request",
   "Address mask reply"
};

#endif // __ICMP_H__


****Main C File ****

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>

    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netdb.h>

    #include "ip.h"
    #include "icmp.h"

    struct timeval timeout;
    struct timeval end;


    #define BUF_SIZE   1024
    #define ICMP       1
    #define ECHO_REQ   8
    #define ECHO_REPL  0
    #define HOSTADDR   "8.8.8.8"

    char *
    iptos (uint32_t ipaddr) {
       static char ips[16];

       sprintf(ips, "%d.%d.%d.%d",
          (ipaddr >> 24),
          (ipaddr >> 16) & 0xff,
          (ipaddr >>  8) & 0xff,
          (ipaddr      ) & 0xff );
       return ips;
    }

    uint16_t
    sum (uint16_t initial, void * buffer, int bytes) {
       uint32_t   total;
       uint16_t * ptr;
       int        words;

       total = initial;
       ptr   = (uint16_t *) buffer;
       words = (bytes + 1) / 2; // +1 & truncation on / handles any odd byte at end

       while (words--) total += *ptr++;
       while (total & 0xffff0000) total = (total >> 16) + (total & 0xffff);

       return (uint16_t) total;
    }




    void
    some_function ( ) {

       struct sockaddr_storage peer_addr;
       socklen_t               peer_addrlen;

       struct sockaddr_in      addr;
       struct sockaddr_in      dstaddr;
       struct iphdr   *        ip;
       struct icmphdr *        icmp;
       struct timeval *        sent;
       int skt;
       int sequence;
       long int length;
       fd_set rdfds;
       int ready;
       int rtt;

       char buff [BUF_SIZE];



       skt = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
       if (skt < 0) {
          perror ("socket()");
          exit (1);
       }

       addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
       addr.sin_port        = 0;
       addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

       if (bind (skt, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) {
          perror ("Can't bind socket");
          exit (1);
       }
    printf("aaa");
       ip = (struct iphdr *)buff;
       peer_addrlen = (socklen_t) sizeof (struct sockaddr_storage);

       memset (&dstaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
       dstaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOSTADDR);
       dstaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

       memset (buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
       icmp = (struct icmphdr *) buff;
       icmp->type   = ECHO_REQ;
       icmp->id     = htons(getpid( ) & 0xffff);
       icmp->seqNum = htons(sequence++);

    printf("aabba");


       if (gettimeofday ((struct timeval *)icmp->data, NULL)) {
          perror ("Can't establish send time");
          exit (1);
       }

       length = sizeof(struct icmphdr) + sizeof(struct timeval);
       icmp->checksum = ~htons(sum (0, buff, length));


    printf("aaa");

       if (sendto (skt, buff, length, 0,
             (struct sockaddr *) &dstaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) <= 0) {
          perror ("sendto()");
          exit (1);


    }
    printf("aaa");
     timeout.tv_sec  = 1;
       timeout.tv_usec = 0;
       FD_ZERO(&rdfds);
       FD_SET (skt, &rdfds);

       ready = select (skt + 1, &rdfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
       if (ready < 0) {
          perror ("Select()");
          exit (1);
       }

     memset (buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
       if (recvfrom (skt, buff, sizeof(buff), 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, &peer_addrlen) <= 0) exit (1);

       if (gettimeofday (&end, NULL)) {   // Timestamp reception
          perror ("Can't establish time of receipt");
          exit (1);
       }

       if (ip->version != 4 ||
           sum (0, buff, sizeof(struct iphdr)) != 0xffff ||
           ip->protocol != ICMP)
          exit(1);

       length = ntohs(ip->length) - ip->hdrlen * 4;       // Length of IP payload
       icmp = (struct icmphdr *)((uint32_t *)ip + ip->hdrlen);   // Find ICMP hdr

       if (icmp->type != ECHO_REPL || sum (0, icmp, length) != 0xffff) {
          fprintf (stderr, "Received %s\n", messages[icmp->type]);
          exit (1);
       }


       sent = (struct timeval *)icmp->data;
       if ((rtt = (end.tv_usec - sent->tv_usec) / 100) < 0)
          rtt += 10000;  // We've cycled to a new second
       rtt += (end.tv_sec - sent->tv_sec) * 10000;  // Add any seconds

       printf ("%ld bytes from %s: icmp_req=%d ttl=%d time=%0.1f ms\n",
          length,
          iptos(ntohl(ip->srcip)),
          ntohs(icmp->seqNum),
          ip->ttl,
          ((float)rtt) / 10);

    }
    int main(){
    printf("aaa");
    some_function();
    return(0);

    }
```

Comment: @H2CO3: Code Review for working code only (according to the FAQ).

Comment: @H2CO3 Please don't redirect people to Codereview without reading the FAQ.

Comment: @Yuushi Read that. Dev null is still an option.

Comment: Please show us the content of the missing header files (ip.h and icmp.h)

Comment: Updated with headers, ANY help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the wrong checksum.

Change this line

```
icmp->checksum = htons(sum (0, buff, length));
```

with

```
icmp->checksum = ~(sum (0, buff, length));
```

the sum function already care about byte order, no need to translate it again with `htons`

Comment: Haha, didn't notice, I was trying to vote it up before but it wouldn't let me.